Crypto research paper - deeper understanding
I've recently been working through different research papers to more deeply understand how the schemes work.
I found implementing them in python helped my understanding a lot.
I've seen many people work through schemes algebraically and come to a thorough understanding in a much shorter time. A skill I'd like to acquire.
To start, I started practicing writing proofs (haven't done so before).
Do you have any advice?
If you really want to understand what's happening in a paper, what steps do you go through?
